# Zend Framework 2 request

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I have a problem to request select in where condition:

Notice: Undefined variable: idSous in
C:\wamp\www\zf2\module\Categorie\src\Categorie\Model\CategorieTable.php
on line 26

```
<?php
namespace Categorie\Model;

use Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway;
use Zend\Db\Sql\Select;

class CategorieTable
{    
    protected $tableGateway;

    public function __construct(TableGateway $tableGateway)
    {
        $this->tableGateway = $tableGateway;
    }

    //fonction qui permet d'afficher tous la table "Article" 
    public function fetchAll($idSous)
    {   

        $idSous  = (int) $idSous;
        $resultSet = $this->tableGateway->select(function (Select $select) {
        $select->columns(array('titre_art', 'description_art'))
        ->join('sous_categorie', 'articles.id_sous_categorie = sous_categorie.id_sous_categorie')
        ->where->like('sous_categorie.id_sous_categorie', $idSous);
        });
        return $resultSet;
    }

}
```

but when I use this requet it's run :

```
<?php
namespace Categorie\Model;

use Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway;
use Zend\Db\Sql\Select;

class CategorieTable
{    
    protected $tableGateway;

    public function __construct(TableGateway $tableGateway)
    {
        $this->tableGateway = $tableGateway;
    }

    public function fetchAll($idSous) {
        $idSous  = (int) $idSous;
        $resultSet = $this->tableGateway->select("id_sous_categorie = $idSous");
        var_dump($resultSet);
        return $resultSet;
    }
}
```

Why is my second request run but not the first?

I need get the $idSous in this controller

```
<?php
namespace Categorie\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;

class AgroalimentaireController extends AbstractActionController
{   
    protected $categorieTable;

    public function indexAction($idSous = 2)
    {
        return new ViewModel(array(
            'categorie' => $this->getAnnoncesTable()->fetchAll($idSous),
        ));
    }

    public function getAnnoncesTable()
    {   
        //permet de recupéré les champs de la table "Article"
        if (!$this->categorieTable) {
            $sm = $this->getServiceLocator();
            $this->categorieTable = $sm->get('Categorie\Model\CategorieTable');
        }
        return $this->categorieTable;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there **like->(...)** creating problem? If it is then you can use like as `->where('sous_categorie.id_sous_categorie LIKE '.$idSous.'')` and also you can set `$idSous` as `$idSous="'%".$idSous."%'" ;`

Comment: your solution it's dont't work :(

Comment: when I select a value example:<code> ->where->like('sous_categorie.id_sous_categorie', 1);</code> it's work !

Comment: first you should echo the value of `$idSous` after the line `$idSous  = (int) $idSous;` and be sure that you are getting the value.

Comment: but I need get the value in the controller not in the class CategorieTable

Comment: I have found the solution ^^ $this->tableGateway->select(function (Select $select) "I add" use ($idSous) and It's work !